# Unable to get $.each to work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[A working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/144/#run) without `$.each`

[Failed example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/145/) with `$.each`

I'm using [a pie chart plugin](https://github.com/mmurph211/Chart/blob/master/src/Chart.js) that gets data from the data attributes of `li` to render a pie. I ran into a problem when I tried running the script in `$.each` function. It looks like it fails to get the data from the data attributes of each container. Can anyone figure out how to solve that?

```
function chart(chartid,stats) {
  new Chart.Pie(chartid, {
    showTooltips: true,
    chartMinSize: [200, 200],
    chartMaxSize: [250, 250],
    chartData: stats
  });
}

$('.p_pie').each(function(){
  var chartid = $(this).attr('id'),
      arr = [],
      stats = $(this).find('.stats_area li:not(:first)').map(function() {
    return [$(this).data('value').split(',')];
  }).get();
  chart(chartid,stats);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(stats));
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='myChart' class='fl p_pie'></div>
<ul class='stats_area legend fl shr pieID'>
  <li>Gender</li>
  <li class='pie_0' data-value='Male,2,Male,#6495ED'><em>Male</em><span> 2</span></li>
  <li class='pie_1' data-value='Female,5,Female,#DC143C'><em>Female</em><span> 5</span></li>
</ul>


<div id='myChart2' class='fl p_pie'></div>
 <ul class='stats_area legend fl shr pieID'>
   <li>Age</li>
   <li class='pie_0' data-value='1-10,12,1-10,#6495ED'><em>1-10</em><span> 12</span></li>
   <li class='pie_1' data-value='11-20,25,11-20,#DC143C'><em>11-20</em><span> 25</span></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.p_pie` divs don't contain anything. ;)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/EZ56N/146/) is the jsFiddle showing that `.each()` is working fine.

In the code you gave, your `ul`s aren't inside the `div`s, so each() doesn't find any elements to iterate over!

Now keep in mind that in your code, you select the ID of the current element to create the pie chart in. This means that whatever content you have in your element will be overwritten, as you can see in the jsFiddle above.

To avoid this, just create a new div to contain the chart with the ID that you want, and get the ID of the element to make the chart in from the data-id attribute of the div that contains your data.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/EZ56N/149/) is an example of that.

```
$('.p_pie').each(function () {
    var chartid = $(this).data('id'), // get the data-id attr of the div
        stats = $(this).find('.stats_area li:not(:first)').map(function () {
            return [$(this).data('value').split(',')];
        }).get();
    chart(chartid, stats);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(this).find('.stats_area li:not(:first)')
```

To:

```
$(this).next('.stats_area').find('li:not(:first)')
```

---

`p_pie` are empty divs, what you really want is to scan the `stats_area` that follows.  You can do this in several methods, but because you still need the chart id of the p_pie div, the quickest change is to adjust the code above (before the map).

This can be seen at [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/151/)

Answer (score 0):

It might help you

```
var chartid = $(this).attr('id'),
      arr = [],
      stats = $(this).find('.stats_area li:not(:first)').map(function() {
    return [$(this).find('li[class^="pie_"]').data('value').split(',')];
  }).get();
```